# Can release-key file be reused without password?

Tags: android, signing

I have an app on android market. Which was developed by a developer. He uses this release-key or keystore for all his projects so dont want to give out the password for this. Is there any way to re-use this release-key file to make new version of the app by just using the file and not the password?

Comment: why don't you use a new keystore?

Comment: @SeRPRo - android market is giving an error when i use new keystore that i can not upload a new version of the same app with new key.

Comment: I assume this is for protecting the original app. Nobody should be able to publish the same app under a different account and maybe get paid for somebody elses work. Moreover the sense of signing an app is to make sure only the original author can publish an app with this name. Nobody should be able to "forge" this app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, this is not possible, as the private Key in the Keyring is encrypted with this password. And without the private key you can't sign the app. Simple as that ;-)